# DataGridView selecting a specific row and retrieving its values

Tags: c#, datagridview

What event shall I use in a `DataGridView` considering that the `DataGridView` is full of data and when I click a row of data automatically I would like to retrieve all the data. I've tried using the event `CellContentClick` but it is only activated when I select a column data instead of a row

```
private void dtSearch_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following to good effect. I handle the `MouseDown` event for the `DataGridView` and set the full row to be highlighted so that it is obvious it has been selected (unless of course you already have your full rows being selected).

```
    private void dtSearch_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the cell that was clicked from the location of the mouse pointer

        DataGridView.HitTestInfo htiSelectedCell = dtSearch.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // Make sure that a cell was clicked, and not the column or row headers
            // or the empty area outside the cells. If it is a cell,
            // then select the entire row, set the current cell (to move the arrow to
            // the current row)

            //if (htiSelectedCell.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
            if (htiSelectedCell.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.RowHeader)
            {
                // do stuff here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I would think you could test for `htiSelectedCell.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.RowHeader` instead of, or as well as, the `DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell`.

Comment: an error. it says. "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: Since it would appear that you are only interested in selection by clicking a row header, I've altered my answer to reflect that. However I'd say that @Colin Pear's is probably the better one now that I've removed the code that highlights an entire row based on a cell being clicked.

Comment: @SidHolland In my case The DataGridView should displays only one column i.e StudentName. But when I select the record on the DataGridView I should get all the details to display using other output controls. like name, RollNo, Class, Address etc.. but in the database table contain all the details. Help me how can I get this ?

Comment: @Sanjeev4evr I would suggest you start a new question post with more details. I'm not able to easily understand what the problem you are having is with only a comment. Also, more people will be available to help you out.

Comment: @SidHolland I posted this as a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979149/datagridview-selectionchanged-event-firing-multiple-times

Answer (score 1):

Hows about the [RowHeaderMouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadermouseclick.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CellClick event, and loop through the columns retrieving the row values you want:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);
    }

    public void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        List<object> values = new List<object>();

        int cols = this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count;

        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {               

            values.Add(this.dataGridView1[col, e.RowIndex].Value);
        }
    }
```